# How can you find the maximum aggregate I/O current supply for a Lattice FPGA?

Tags: current, fpga, lattice

I want to find the maximum aggregate I/O current supply for the MachXO3D (9400HC) breakout board to ensure that I do not damage it. All pins will be using the LVCMOS33 I/O standard. I have been up and down the datasheet for hours to no avail and I suspect that this may be something that has to be inferred using some sort of calculation, but I am currently at a total loss.

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the [MachXO3D Family Data Sheet](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=52590) (linked from the [MachXO3D Enhance Secure Control Applications with Hardware Root-of-Trust and Dual Boot Capabilities](https://www.latticesemi.com/Products/FPGAandCPLD/MachXO3D#_75DB2E3AFC32420487D106A30252597E) documentation) there is the following note in the *3.12. sysI/O Single-Ended DC Electrical Characteristics* section:

> 4. For electromigration, the average DC current sourced or sinked by I/O pads between two consecutive VCCIO or GND pad connections,
>    or between the last VCCIO or GND in an I/O bank and the end of an I/O bank, as shown in the Logic Signal Connections table (also
>    shown as I/O grouping) **shall not exceed a maximum of n * 8 mA**. “n” is the number of I/O pads between the two consecutive bank
>    VCCIO or GND connections or between the last VCCIO and GND in a bank and the end of a bank. I/O Grouping can be found in the Data
>    Sheet Pin Tables, which can also be generated from the Lattice Diamond software.

I can't find anything else in the datasheet about the *maximum aggregate I/O current supply*.